# Is there any way to topRight align ExpansionTile trailing icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make the expansionTile trailing icon top align. by default it aligns to the center, below I have attached the screenshot of the desired output.

[image]

```dart
  ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          child: ExpansionTile(
            tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            collapsedBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(24, 34, 62, 1),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(24, 34, 62, 1),
            iconColor: Colors.white,
            collapsedIconColor: Colors.white,
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            title: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "text".toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 248, 26),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'How to make trailing icon top align   ',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 249, 85, 1),
                                    fontSize: 12),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 80),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(226, 80, 95, 1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
                                child: Text(
                                  'label',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '40%',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 248, 26),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            children: const <Widget>[
              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
            ],
          ),
        ),`
```

here's the link to my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gaurav501/pen/jOzoEMZ)

Comment: Can you include current code snippet?

Comment: i need to check your code first

Comment: I have edited  the  post with the codepen link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom widget for this, I am using `Transform`offset to handle it.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ValueNotifier<bool> isExpanded = ValueNotifier(false);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              collapsedBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(24, 34, 62, 1),
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(24, 34, 62, 1),
              iconColor: Colors.white,
              collapsedIconColor: Colors.white,
              expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              trailing: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(0, -7), //half of padding
                child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: isExpanded,
                  builder: (context, value, child) => AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    child: Icon(value
                        ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined
                        : Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                isExpanded.value = value;
              },
              title: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "text".toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 248, 26),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 12),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'How to make trailing icon top align   ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 249, 85, 1),
                                      fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                  constraints:
                                      const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 80),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(226, 80, 95, 1),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'label',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 10,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '40%',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 248, 26),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              children: const <Widget>[
                ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]